# When a statement contains an item in a list, show it in a new column

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would appreciate a little help on some script in sql. So I have a list like the one below and a database table -Table1 with statement as a colum name, and I will like to create a column called location, where the script can search in the statement column and once it finds any of the items in the list in any row it states that in the location column

(Tema, london, Sydney, Germany, China, Africa,)

```
Statement 
-------------------
Going to london
Apples in Tema
Sydney is a city
China is a country
Africa is a continent
```

In the end I hope to see a table like this :

| Statement | location |
| --- | --- |
| Going to london | London |
| Apples in Tema | Tema |
| Sydney is a city | Sydney |
| china is a country | China |
| Africa is a continent | Africa |

By using this script,

```
SELECT Statement, 
Case
WHEN Statement::text ~~* '%london%'::character varying::text
    THEN 'london'::character varying
      ELSE NULL::character varying
        END AS location
FROM Table1
```

I think I would have to write a very tall script, but I was wondering if I could get help with something efficient and quite simple to achieve this

Comment: We would need very rigid and defined rules for how to identify the place proper name.  Otherwise, you might need a grammar parsing library (and SQL isn't the best place to be doing that).

Comment: In addition to @TimBiegeleisen comment, you have a mix of countries and cities, which doesn't help to solve your problem

Comment: I was hoping to use a defined list like the one in the parenthesis. where once it searches the text in the statement column and compares to the list, and finds a match of the word, it picks that word into the location column, if it doesn't it puts a null

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of places, you can use that:

```
select t1.*, v.place
from table1 t1 cross join
     (values ('tema'), ('london'), ('sydney'), ('germany'), ('china'), ('africa')
     ) v(place)
     on Statement::text ilike '%' || v.place || '%';
```

Note:  You might want to use regular expressions so you can include work boundaries but your example code doesn't do tis.